# GNP/GDP and modelling

Tags: programming, modeling, models, continuous-time

Is GNP a continuous, static or a dynamic model ? What about GDP ? What I do know is that it has yearly discrete values. However, when it is modeled, it becomes a continuous graph. So what exactly is the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, GNP and GDP are economic time series and they are not economic model.

Secondly, you can also get these time series with different frequency, as quarterly data, avalaible on [OECD](http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=350) website. In the case you need for lower frequency data you can get it by interpolation (as, for instance, the cubic spline interpolation); This is the [Matlab tutorial](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) for conducting the cubic spline interpolation.

Lastly, as regards the graph you did, I am not sure to underastand completely your question; anyway, it is continuous simply because the software link all time series points together in the graph, but this doesn't mean that you have a continuous function; you have a continuous graph that describe a discrete function.

Comment: Also, the time series reported by for example OECD are estimates of the actual time series. No one measures economic activity in the sense that they take all economic activity into account.